# DDWRT cannot ping gateway, but it can ping everything else in network

Tags: dd-wrt, wireless-bridge

I'm making a wifi bridge between my ISP router/gateway (P-2812HNU-F1, 192.168.1.254) and my DDWRT wrt320n router bridge client (192.168.1.2). Now I've got most of it running accept for one big problem which I can't seem to figure out.

What I can't do is ping from a computer (with a static ip) to the gateway from the side of the bridge client.

What I can do is ping everything else in my network from that same computer. No matter which side or device I'm on, wired/wifi, I can ping it all. Except for the gateway.

From a computer on the side of the gateway I can ping everything just fine. Even the gateway.

Seeing the gateway runs the dhcp show I obviously can't get an IP either. That is why the IP of the client side computer is static for now.

I have checked if there is a firewall on the gateway, but no.
No mac block
No NAT settings
No vlan
subnet are both 255.255.255.0

I'm really plucking my hair here. Am I missing something specific?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should read it more carefully then. The question is clear: Why can't I ping my gateway even though I can ping all else in my network.

Comment: It's a bridge, so everything is one network. The computer in particular is wired to the ddwrt router.

Comment: Both single channel ?

Comment: They both run on channel six if I understand your question right.

Comment: ah, that channel. Good question, I'll check that.

Comment: The gateway runs b/g/n (no specific ghz can be found, so I'm guessing 2.4)
The wrt is running "mixed"

Comment: How did you bridge them?

Comment: both wpa2 psk aes

Comment: That won't bridge them automatically I would recommend googling on how to build wireless bridge you have to do site survey locate your primary and connect

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I have that survey up and running.

Comment: Connect to both of them using Ethernet and find out where the link is broken at this point it's not clear

Comment: What kind of bridging are you using? WDS? Or some kind of fake bridging based on NAT, sometimes called "repeating" or "repeater bridging"?

Answer (score 0):

***Creating wireless bridge***

https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge

***After bridge if ping doesn't work between routers*** 
1. Make sure you ISP router is in NAT mode
 2. There should be setting under you Lam settings on your primary router to switch between bridge vs Nat change that to nat and reboot all routers
 3. On Dd-wrt router : sizable local dhcp and forward all shop requests to primary router

Creating witel a

Comment: I have put it in Full cone NAT. No joy.

Comment: If you connect using Ethernet to both of these routers one by one are you able to ping?

Comment: I might not understand correct, but from the gateway side I can ping everything in the LAN.
From the wrt side only the gateway is unreachable